# Windows 10 battery usage information is incomplete

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, battery

I have been trying to test my laptop's battery recently but I have found an issue where the battery usage breakdown in the settings app is incomplete. Screenshots on the internet show percentage values for "System", "Display" and "WiFi" but these do not exist on my machine. I have no memory of these statistics ever existing on my laptop and I only found out about them by seeing screenshots of other people's settings apps.

Below is an image  of a screenshot from the internet where the readouts are visible and a screenshot from my computer where they do not exist.

[image: Two screenshots of the 'battery usage' section in the settings app]

The computer is a new Lenovo ThinkPad with the original battery and Windows 10 Home 1607 (64 bit).

Comment: First, this is probably from an older Windows 10 version (RTM, 1511, whatever). As you can see, the design of the Settings app is different. Also, it’s very likely getting those statistics requires some sort of power usage profile from the manufacturer which you’re most likely lacking.

Comment: @DanielB Ah, that would make sense. Is there some driver I can install or am I unable to gain this functionality?